# Firebase JS9 access subcollection with DocumentSnapshot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

Just quick question.
How to do something like this in firebase javascript v9? `userDoc` is a DocumentSnapshot .

```js
const postRef = userDoc.ref.collection('posts').doc(slug);
```

I need to access sub-collection with doc snapshot, but I am totally clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the document reference to the `collection` function, and the collection ref that gives to the `doc` function:

```
const postRef = doc(collection(userDoc.ref, 'posts', slug));
```

---

Alternatively, you can skip the `collection` call here as both `collection` and `doc` accept multiple arguments:

```
const postRef = doc(userDoc.ref, 'posts', slug);
```